# How are the standard errors of fixed effects computed in a mixed-effects model?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, standard-error

**Question**: Is it possible to write a mathematical expression for the standard errors of the fixed effect coefficients from an mixed-effects model in terms of model parameters, and not matrix operations?

**Motivation**
I want to analyze (simulated) data from a cluster randomized (10 schools in this case) experiment with repeated measurements of the participants (30 students per school in this case) in each cluster. The design can be outlined with the following figure:

[image: Experimental Design]

I'm interested in the fixed effects of time and treatment. My initial intuition was that a mixed effects model with random intercepts for each school and random intercepts for each student would give a more precise estimate of the fixed effects than a model that ignored the clustering in schools. However, when I compared the two models, I was surprised to see that the standard error of the treatment fixed effect was *higher* when including the random intercepts for schools (0.895 when ignoring schools, 1.527 when including random intercepts for schools).

```r
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
ASAP <- read.csv("https://science.smith.edu/~whopper/ASAP.csv")

model1 <- lmer(outcome ~ year * treatment + (1 | studentID),
               data = ASAP
               )
summary(model1)$coefficients
#>                          Estimate Std. Error     t value
#> (Intercept)             8.3650004  0.6333830  13.2068600
#> year11th                4.9551280  0.1127886  43.9328973
#> year9th                -4.9440374  0.1127886 -43.8345660
#> treatmentTRUE           0.2851455  0.8957388   0.3183356
#> year11th:treatmentTRUE -2.7188822  0.1595071 -17.0455239
#> year9th:treatmentTRUE   3.1644549  0.1595071  19.8389587

model2 <- lmer(outcome ~ year * treatment + (1 | studentID) + (1 | schoolID),
               data = ASAP
               )
summary(model2)$coefficients
#>                          Estimate Std. Error     t value
#> (Intercept)             8.3650004  1.0794044   7.7496444
#> year11th                4.9551280  0.1127886  43.9328976
#> year9th                -4.9440374  0.1127886 -43.8345664
#> treatmentTRUE           0.2851455  1.5265084   0.1867959
#> year11th:treatmentTRUE -2.7188822  0.1595071 -17.0455241
#> year9th:treatmentTRUE   3.1644549  0.1595071  19.8389589
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

After thinking for a bit, I realized perhaps this makes sense. Without acknowledging the clustering within schools, the treatment effect appears very consistent, showing up as successful in hundreds of students. But, the treatment was actually randomized at the level of schools, not students; now that the model can "see" this, we have a bit less confidence in the treatment effect, since it's *really* only observed in a few school instead of hundreds of students.

I was hoping I could find a mathematical expression for these standard errors that would show me the individual 'ingredients' that go into a standard error, so I could assess this intuition, but haven't been very successful so far. I have read that for a mixed effects model of the form

$$
y = X\beta + Zb + \varepsilon
$$

the standard errors of the fixed effects are the square roots of the diagonal of the variance/covariance matrix of the fixed effects, and this covariance matrix is given by:

$$
{\rm Var}(\hat\beta)=(X'VX)^{-1} 
$$

where $X$ is the $n \times k$ fixed effects design matrix, and $V$ is an $n \times n$ block diagonal matrix giving the observation-level variance/covariance matrix, and can be computed from

$$
V = ZGZ' + \sigma^2 I
$$

where $Z$ is the $n \times k$ random effects design matrix, $G$ is the $j \times j$ covariance matrix of the random effects, and $\sigma I$ is a $n \times n$ matrix with the residual variance on the diagonal and 0 on the off diagonals. Cribbing some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650548/get-residual-variance-covariance-matrix-in-lme4), this does seem to be the case for `lmer` models, whew!

```r
G <- crossprod(getME(model1, "Lambdat"))
Z <- getME(model1,"Z")
sigma2 <- sigma(model1)^2

V_tmp <- sigma2*(Z %*% G %*% t(Z))
sI <- sigma2 * Diagonal(nrow(ASAP))
V <- V_tmp + sI

X <- model.matrix(model1)
beta_covariance <- solve(t(X) %*% solve(V)  %*% X)
sqrt(diag(beta_covariance)) # compare to Std. Error column for model 1 above
#           (Intercept)               year11th                year9th 
#                 0.633                  0.113                  0.113 
#         treatmentTRUE year11th:treatmentTRUE  year9th:treatmentTRUE 
#                 0.896                  0.160                  0.160
```

But, seeing the standard error computations in matrix operations doesn't really help me understand them much.

I'm thinking of how the variance/covariance matrix of coefficients in a bivariate OLS regression can be expressed as

$$
\widehat{\textrm{Var}}(\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}) = \hat{\sigma}^2  (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1}
$$

which is compact and generalizable, but fairly opaque. However, this matrix could also be expressed as

$$
\widehat{\textrm{Var}}(\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}) = \left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}{n\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i^2-\bar{x}^2)} &
-\frac{\sigma^2\bar{x}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i^2-\bar{x}^2)} \\
-\frac{\sigma^2\bar{x}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i^2-\bar{x}^2)} &
\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i^2-\bar{x}^2)}
  \end{array}
  \right]
$$

which is specific to a bivariate OLS regression, but clearly shows you the specific "ingredients" that increase or decrease the standard error of each coefficient.

To bring all this to a close, I'll reiterate my main questions:

- Is it possible to write a mathematical expression for the standard errors of the fixed effect coefficients from an random intercepts model in terms of model parameters, without using matrix operations?
- If so, what is the expression for the standard error of the fixed effects from a random intercepts model like my model 1 and model 2?